# Interview test - adding using A Recursive Algorithm c#

Tags: c#

Below is an interview question about using recursion to add two arrays.

I can't figure it out though because it does not seem to allow any kind of index to keep track of where you are, I have been down a few roads - trying to test for null / default values in the array but because it is a byte[] type nothing worked.

Any help would be great thanks - this is not a homework question.

```
public AddResult UsingARecursiveAlgorithm_ValuesAreAdded(byte[] a, byte[] b)
{
    var result = AddRecursive(a, b);

    // Assert

    return new AddResult(a, b, result);
}
```

e.g.

> Input : { 1, 1, 1 }, { 1, 1, 1 }
>
> Result: { 2, 2, 2 }
>
> Input : { 1, 1, 255 }, { 0, 0, 1 }
>
> Result: { 1, 2, 0 }

Conditions:

a & b are never null, and are always of the same length.

The algorithm should be non destructive to the inputs.

Edit: the second result is incorrect. It should be { 1,1,0 } -that's the way it was presented though.

Comment: I thought I understood the problem after your first example, but the second one doesn't make sense. Aren't you adding the corresponding entries from the two arrays? I don't understand how you end up with 0 in the third position in your second example.

Comment: FWIW I think these sorts of interview questions are a bit silly

Comment: @CraigW. 255+1 = 0 when you're a byte.

Comment: Yes it's more confusing that the result in the second example second position is 2 ... 0 + 1 == 2 ?

Comment: Dweeberly: 1 is carried over...

Comment: @Blorgbeard: I keep forgetting they were byte arrays and not int arrays.

Comment: Added an edit there; I also assume it should be  { 1,1,0 }

Comment: Vaguely reminds me of a ripple-carry adder.  But base `2^8` instead of base `2^1`.  If you think like lisp using `car` and `cdr` you might make some progress.

Comment: I eventually posted a working sample. If that is helpful, please upvote or accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Ok here is some rather "ugly" code that does what you want.  I tried to write it for clarity rather than brevity:

```
static byte[] AddArray(byte[] ary1, byte[] ary2) {
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(ary1.Length == ary2.Length);
    if ((ary1 == null) || (ary2 == null)) {
        throw new ArgumentException("Empty or null array");
    }
    // sum the last element
    var ix = ary1.Length - 1;
    var sum = (ary1[ix] + ary2[ix]);
    if (sum > byte.MaxValue) {
        if (ix == 0) {
            throw new ArgumentException("Overflow");
        }
        // Add carry by recursing on ary1
        var carry = (byte) (sum - byte.MaxValue);
        var carryAry = new byte[ary1.Length];
        carryAry[ix - 1] = carry;
        ary1 = AddArray(ary1, carryAry);
    }

    if ((ary1.Length == 1) || (ary2.Length == 1)) {
        return new byte[] { (byte) sum }; // end recursion
    }
    // create the remainder, elements from 0 it (len-1)
    var ary1Remainder = new byte[ary1.Length - 1];
    var ary2Remainder = new byte[ary2.Length - 1];
    Array.Copy(ary1, 0, ary1Remainder, 0, ary1.Length - 1);
    Array.Copy(ary2, 0, ary2Remainder, 0, ary2.Length - 1);
    // recurse
    var remainder = AddArray(ary1Remainder, ary2Remainder);
    // build return array (using linq Concat)
    var rv = (remainder.Concat(new byte[] { (byte) sum }));
    return rv.ToArray(); // return as an array 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private int carry = 0;        
public byte[] AddRecursive(byte[] a, byte[] b)
{
    //Start from bottom of the byte[] array
    a = a.Reverse().ToArray();
    b = b.Reverse().ToArray();
    if (a.Length == 0) return new byte[] { };            
    int tempresult = a[0] + b[0] + carry;
    byte[] z = new byte[]
    { (byte)(tempresult) };
    carry = tempresult / (byte.MaxValue + 1);
    return z.Concat(AddRecursive(a.Skip(1).ToArray(), b.Skip(1).ToArray())).ToArray();
}

//Test//

[Test]
public void Add_UsingARecursiveAlgorithm_ValuesAreAdded()
{
    //First Test
    byte[] expectedResult = addthisaddthat.AddRecursive(new byte[] { 1, 1, 1 }, new byte[] { 1, 1, 1 }).Reverse().ToArray();
    Assert.That(expectedResult, Is.EqualTo(new byte[] { 2, 2, 2 }));
    //Sec Test
    expectedResult = addthisaddthat.AddRecursive(new byte[] { 1, 1, 255 }, new byte[] { 0, 0, 1 }).Reverse().ToArray();
    Assert.That(expectedResult, Is.EqualTo(new byte[] { 1, 2, 0 }));
    //Third Test
    expectedResult = addthisaddthat.AddRecursive(new byte[] { 255, 255, 255 }, new byte[] { 255, 255, 255 }).Reverse().ToArray();
    Assert.That(expectedResult, Is.EqualTo(new byte[] { 255, 255, 254 }));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This would be cleaner without all the casting and `ToArray` required because the values are `byte[]` and not `IEnumerable<int>`, but:

```
private byte[] AddRecursive(byte[] a, byte[] b) {

    if (a.Length == 0) return new byte[]{};

    return 
        new byte[] { (byte)(a[0] + b[0]) }.Concat(
        AddRecursive(a.Skip(1).ToArray(), b.Skip(1).ToArray())
        ).ToArray();
}
```

Comment: Your code fails at the 2nd example, you did not carry the 1 from the first column in to the second. https://dotnetfiddle.net/WYhzXk

Comment: OP clarified it was a typo, no carry required.

Comment: Hi, this seem to work well. Its a clever solution, thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Maybe your interviewer had something like this in mind:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static byte[] Add(byte[] a, byte[] b, int index = -1)
    {
        if (index < 0)
        {
            return Add((byte[])a.Clone(), b, 0);
        }
        if (index < a.Length)
        {
            Add(a, b, index + 1);
            a[index] += b[index];
        }
        return a;
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var r1 = Add(new byte[] { 1, 1, 1 }, new byte[] { 1, 1, 1 });
        var r2 = Add(new byte[] { 1, 1, 255 }, new byte[] { 0, 0, 1 });
        var r3 = Add(new byte[] { 0, 100, 200 }, new byte[] { 3, 2, 1 });
        // Outputs: 2, 2, 2
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", r1.Select(n => "" + n).ToArray()));
        // Outputs: 1, 1, 0
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", r2.Select(n => "" + n).ToArray()));
        // Outputs: 3, 102, 201
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", r3.Select(n => "" + n).ToArray()));
    }
}
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/UqSQb3

<s>Note this (only partial) solution doesn't handle the carry on byte overflows, though.</s>

'Hope this helps,

Comment: Your second line is giving the wrong answer. it should be `1,2,0` because a unchecked overflow should cause the next item to the left to be incremented by 1.